# most efficient way to convert decimal to base 64 using Python

Tags: python, performance, url, base64, processing-efficiency

What is the most efficient way to convert decimal into base 64 (URL friendly) and back.

My current code,

```
import numpy as np

a = "-0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLM64OPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
A = {k:i for i,k in enumerate(a)}


def dec_url(x:int, n:int=4):
    o = []
    for i in range(n):
        m = x%(64**(i+1))
        x -= m
        o.append(a[m//(64**i)])
    return ''.join(o[::-1])

def url_dec(s: str):
    return np.sum(map(lambda i:A.get(i[1])*(64**(i[0])),enumerate(s[::-1])))
```

Comment: what do you mean by "most efficient"? As an aside, why did you do `sum(list(map(...)))`? What's the point of `list`?

Comment: use the base64 built-in module?

Comment: Do you have reason to assume that implementing your own from scratch is going to be more efficient than using the available, debugged, and presumably frequently profiled library functions from [the `base64` module in Python's standard library?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) Or didn't you find it?

Comment: @triplee Kurt I am trying to implement my own function for purely educational purposes. And I'm looking for ways to more efficiently build this from scratch. :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the tip. I had no idea that you pass a map object through sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better methods to encode a variable length integer, so for education purposes only:

```
from functools import reduce

def dec_url(x:int, n:int=4):
    o = []
    while x:
        x, m = divmod(x, 64)
        o.append(a[m])
    return ''.join(reversed(o))

def url_dec(s: str):
    return reduce((lambda total, char: (total << 6) + A[char]), s, 0)
```